# Make clang-format break after __attribute__

Tags: c, clang-format

I have a function that want to be formatted like this:

```
__attribute__((naked, noreturn))
void _reset(void) {
    ...
}
```

But clang-format does this:

```
__attribute__((naked, noreturn)) void _reset(void) {
    ...
}
```

I tried to add `//` after attribute list to prevent clang-format from removing line break but for some reason it gets even worse:

```
__attribute__((naked, noreturn)) //
void
_reset(void) {
    ...
}
```

I tried to raise `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine` value but it didn't change anything.

How do I make clang-format break after attribute list?

UPD. If I just put `\` symbol after `__attribute__((naked, noreturn))` then it gets formatted out and function definition is set back to the same line. However, if I put   (a space) after `\`, then it is formatted like that:

```
__attribute__((naked, noreturn)) \ 
void
_reset(void) {
    ...
}
```

What the hell is going on?..

Comment: Newlines in code are only for readability.  If you are concerned with appearances only, could you simply use a C line extension character:  `"\"`?  i.e.  `__attribute__((naked, noreturn)) \"` .  FWIW C, execution flow is not determined by newlines (or breaks), but by certain other characters such as the statement terminator `;`, or by brackets `{...}` and others, but never by `\n`.

Comment: That is: a single backslash \ without any ".

Comment: \ just gets formatted out... nvm it's even worse, check the answer please

Comment: There's `BreakAfterAttributes: Always` but it only impacts C++ [[attributes]]. I think this is a bug. I've always found the way clang-format deals with `__attribute__` to be unpleasant. Even adding a `//` to the end of the line doesn't help. The only workaround I've found is to do things like `#define NOINLINE __attribute__((__noinline__))`. Someone should file an issue with LLVM.

Comment: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/83689